# $M ⊗_B U$ is fnitely generated projective as a right $A$-module

Tags: modules

Let $A, B$ be $k$-algebras. $M$ is $A$-$B$-bimodule that is finitely generated projective as a left $A$-module and as a right $B$-module, $N, U$ are $B$-$A$-bimodules that is finitely generated projective as a left $B$-module and as a right $A$-module.

As a left $B$-module, $U$ is a direct summand of $B^n$ for some positive integer $n$, hence $M ⊗_B U$ is a direct summand of $M^n$ as a left $A$-module. This shows that $M ⊗_B U$ is fnitely generated projective as a left $A$-module. A similar argument shows that $M ⊗_B U$ is finitely generated projective as a right $A$-module.

I can't see how a similar argument works. I tried and found I cannot tensor with M anymore as $A$ is not a $B$-module. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $A-B$ is parsed as $A$ *minus* $B$. If you want hyphens, do not put `-` between dollar signs.

Comment: noted. will keep that in mind

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. You say *I can't see how a similar argument works.* but I cannot understand what you're talking about.

Comment: thx! I meant how to use direct summand and tensoring argument to show this since the author used the word similar.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that $M\otimes_B U$ is finitely generated projective as a right $A$-module. I suppose you can see it is finitely generated, so let us check that the functor
$$X\longmapsto\hom_A(M\otimes_B U,X)$$
is exact. By adjunction, this functor is equal to
$$X\longmapsto\hom_B(M,\hom_A(U,X))$$
and this is a composition of two functors that are exact, since $M$ and $U$ are projective.